# \enquote command of biblatex and \providecommand

Tags: biblatex, macros

I'm not so sure whether I am asking a question about `biblatex` or about `\providecommand` but I hope someone can help me.

It occurs to me that both `csquotes` and `biblatex` define an `\enquote` command (I could not find it in the documentation of `biblatex` however).

At least, both

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
    \enquote{asdf}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}
    \enquote{asdf}
\end{document}
```

compile perfectly fine.

If I include the line `\providecommand{\enquote}{\emph}`, the version with `csquotes` still works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\providecommand{\enquote}{\emph}

\begin{document}
    \enquote{asdf}
\end{document}
```

But the version with `biblatex` gives an error `Command \enquote already defined. \begin{document}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\providecommand{\enquote}{\emph}

\begin{document}
    \enquote{asdf}
\end{document}
```

Also `\enquote{asdf}` is printed as italics, which, to my understanding of `\providecommand` should not be the case if `biblatex` already defined the `\enquote` command.

Comment: I don't think `biblatex` provides that command. It assumes that you should load `csquotes` which does. It does that to enable you to modify quote styles easily, but precisely so that it doesn't clash with `enquote` which is useful independently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`biblatex` tests if `csquotes` has been loaded. If not it assumes that `\enquote` is undefined and defines it itself with `\newrobustcmd*`. The test is done in `\AtEndPreamble`, directly before `\begin{document}`.

So your failing example is equivalent to this here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\providecommand{\enquote}{\emph}
\newcommand\enquote{blub}
\begin{document}
    \enquote{asdf}
\end{document}
```

The `\enquote` command of `biblatex` is not so powerful as the one from `csquotes`. E.g. it doesn't take languages into account:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}
    \enquote{asdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very good explanation. I myself am writing a small package where I need an `\enquote` command. I want it to make use of `csquotes` if that package is loaded, but be a more primitive version if not. *Usually* I have loaded both `csquotes` and `biblatex`. What would be your suggestion how to accomplish this? Should I copy the approach of `biblatex` and test for both `csquotes` and `biblatex` at the end of the preamble?

Comment: Mhh, maybe `biblatex` should not define `\enquote` itself if `csquotes` is not loaded, but should rather use a private name ... The fact that `biblatex` defines `\enquote` is not documented, either ...

Comment: Started a discussion in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/737